# grep -- removing text after delimiter token

Tags: command-line, scripting, grep, sed

I have a file in which I need to eliminate everything after the first `;` on every line.

So a file like this:

```
sdfsdsdf;
fsdfsddf;sdfsd;
```

Will result in this:

```
sdfsdsdf
fsdfsddf
```

I have looked into `grep` and `sed`.  I would appreciate an answer incorporating either of these commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` is probably easiest and faster than awk or perl in this circumstance:

```
sed 's/^\([^;][^;]*\);.*$/\1/' some_file_name
```

Comment: This is more complicated than it should be! `sed 's/;.*//'`

Comment: I beg to differ. perl -pe 's/;.*//' some_file_name is just as easy, and arguably up to 1500% faster when operating in large files.

Comment: I have several systems where sed is available but perl is not, so I encourage using lighter-weight solutions where they suffice.

Answer (score 10):

another option is to use the `cut` command

```
cat a.file | cut -d';' -f1
```

Comment: useless us of cat

Answer (score 3):

I typically use `awk` for things like this:

`cat a.file | awk -F=";" '{ print $1 }'`

That will take each line of a file and print the first group before the delimiter `-F`

Comment: useless use of `cat`.

Comment: Second Dennis there. And under linux and BSD that -F=";" does not work as intended. And you might want to quote that $1, too: awk -F";" '{print $1}' a.file

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po "^[^;]+(?=;?)" filename
```

Comment: Without Gnu grep: `grep -Eo '^[^;]+;' filename` almost gets it, it just prints one character too many. `grep -Eo '^[^;]+' filename` almost gets it too, but it will also print complete (non-empty) lines that don't have any `;`.